# Run azure devops pipeline on every available pool

Tags: azure-devops

I'm evaluating Azure Devops and want to have following workflow: I want to have a pipeline build and run it on our self-hosted build agent, but if non them is available I want to fall back on hosted agent and vice versa. According to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops in the yaml file you need to define in which pool will job run.

Can I have a pipeline build without having to define a pool/define many pools as fallback?

Comment: I have added a feature request here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-Pipelines-YAML:-Select-any-agent/1512280